# Total variation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I cannot decide if the next function has bounded variation:
in the segment $(0,1)$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{m^{2} n^{2}},&\text{if $x$ is rational}\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
the rational $x$ is $m/n$ and it is the reduced form.

so far  showed  it is not absolute continuous

thanks

Comment: Please let me know if I edited it correctly. Regards

Comment: do $m,n$ have any special relation? e.g. is the rational number $m/n$ or something like that?

Comment: the edition is correct. the rational number is m/n.

Comment: Presumable for $x=m/n$ written in reduced form? Please correct your post.

Comment: "Reduced". Or "irreducible"... :-)

Answer (score 4):

More generally, assume that $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ with the exception that $f(x_n)=a_n$ for some countable set $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ and some nonnegative sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges.

Then $f=g-h$ where
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\mathbb 1_{x\geqslant x_n},\qquad h(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\mathbb 1_{x\gt x_n}.
$$
Since $g$ and $h$ are both finite valued and nondecreasing, $f$ has finite variation.

Can you prove that the function $f$ in your post fits this setting, that is, that $f$ corresponds to some $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges?